# Pytest how to freeze and test a flask endpoint that uses datetime.now()

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, pytest

suppose I have an endpoint in app.py

```
@app.route('/endpoint', methods=['GET'])
def endpoint():
  response = app_lib.get_data()
  return jsonify(response..)
```

then we have get_data() in app_lib.py

```
from datetime import datetime
def get_data():
  data = some_data_base_fetch()
  res = []
  for i in data:
      if i.time < datetime.now()
          res.append(i)
   return res
```

`some_data_base_fetch()` is fetching some books from the database, which includes book names, book time etc. I want to freeze the `datetime.now()` for this particular endpoint during testing so I can control the time here.

I'm not doing unit testings. I am doing some endpoint testings here. So I call the endpoint and compare the response only..

Answer (score -1):

You can use the freezegun library to freeze the datetime.now() to a specific value during testing. Here's how you could do it:

1. Install freezegun via pip:

```html
pip install freezegun
```

2. Modify your app_lib.py to allow an optional now argument in
   get_data():

```html
from datetime import datetime

def get_data(now=None):
    data = some_data_base_fetch()
    res = []
    for i in data:
        if now is None:
            now = datetime.now()
        if i.time < now:
            res.append(i)
    return res
```

3. In your test file, use freezegun to temporarily set the time while making requests to your endpoint:

```html
import pytest
from freezegun import freeze_time
import requests

@freeze_time("2022-01-01")
def test_endpoint():
    response = requests.get('http://your-server/endpoint')
    expected_response = ...  # Whatever response you expect
    assert response.json() == expected_response
```

In this example, during the execution of test_endpoint, anytime datetime.now() is called within your application, it will return 2022-01-01. This way, you can control the time while testing your endpoint.

However, note that this method modifies the get_data function to accept an optional now argument, which may not be suitable depending on your application structure and requirements. If that's the case, you might need to explore other mocking or testing strategies to control the time during your tests.